# OAuth2.0 Authentication fails w/ Mailkit

Tags: oauth-2.0, mailkit

I am trying to authenticate a desktop application but all the time I get Authentication failed exception.
I am using the following code:

```
const string Username = "user@contoso.com";
using (var client = new ImapClient(new ProtocolLogger("imap.log")))
{
    client.Connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, true);
    if (client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Contains("OAUTHBEARER") || client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Contains("XOAUTH2"))
        AuthenticateAsync(client).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    client.Disconnect(true);
}

static async Task AuthenticateAsync(ImapClient client)
{
    var options = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "Client Id",
        TenantId = "Tenant Id",
        RedirectUri = "http://localhost:8080"
    };

    var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
        .CreateWithApplicationOptions(options)
        .Build();

    var scopes = new string[] {
        "email",
        "offline_access",
        "IMAP.AccessAsUser.All"
    };

    var authToken = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();


    if (client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Contains("OAUTHBEARER"))
        oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuthBearer(Username, authToken.AccessToken);
    else
        oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(Username, authToken.AccessToken);

    await client.AuthenticateAsync(oauth2);
}
```

I've the following permission for my app on the Azure portal:

```
email
IMAP.AccessAsUser.All
offline_access
User.Read
```

Line : AuthenthicateAsyng(client).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); throws exception[1][MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDvUv.png)

Comment: You probably need to use `"https://outlook.office.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All"` instead of `"IMAP.AccessAsUser.All"`. In any event, follow these directions: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md

Comment: I've already tried that scope and still not working, it keeps throwing Authentication failed.

Comment: @FabrizioChavezInsegna could you find a way to make it work? we're also having the same issue.